# Modifying a copy of the seatle.master instead of a copy of seatle.html

Tags: 2013, development, master-page, page-layout, custom-masterpage

I wanted to do some modification to the seatle master page. So I took a copy of the Seatle.master using share point designer , and I paste it , then I rename the new file to custom.master. I wrote some javascripts and I hide & move some components inside the custom.master, then I save the custom.master and I set it as a default master page. As follow:-

[image]

My first question is :-

But I have read that I should not edit any of the .master pages and that I need to do all the modifications to the .html version? So can anyone advice what is wrong with modifying the .master instead of the .html?

Second question:-  I know that SharePoint can convert a modified .html file to a .master file,  but it will not do the other way. So is there any service within SharePoint that allow me to convert the  current modified .master file to .html file. So that the two files will be consistent ?

Third question. inside my current publishing site i also modified the EnterPriseWiki.aspx page layout using SharePoint designer, so should this also be avoided and why ?

Thanks

Comment: Please, only ask one question per post

Comment: i though they are related together and it will be easier to answer them at once.

Comment: @RobertLindgren so can u advice on them please?